# Removing certain lines in python 3.0

Tags: python-3.x, icalendar

I have an .ics file that i need to remove the VTIMEZONE lines from

What is the easiest way to remove everything from (and including) BEGIN:VTIMEZONE to END:VTIMEZONE

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//TEST//TEST//EN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:UTC+11
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20170101
TZNAME:UTC+11
TZOFFSETFROM:+1100
TZOFFSETTO:+1100
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:Testing
DTEND;TZID=UTC+11:20170228T233000
DTSTAMP:20170227T064302Z
DTSTART;TZID=UTC+11:20170228T230000
UID:1961094_636238800000000000
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Reason i am doing this is iCalendar library is not parsing the file when the vtimezone is included. the DTSTART and DTEND cannot be processes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with calendar files however the following code (comments provided for explanation):

```
with open("help.ics","r") as input_file:
    #read in each line as a list
        input_lines = input_file.readlines()

        with open("newhelp.ics","w") as output_file:      

            #variable to determine whether to write file to new file or not
            keep_lines = True

            #loop thorugh every line
            for line in input_lines:
                if line == "BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\n":
                    #When the BEGIN:VTIMEZONE line is reached, stop writing lines
                    keep_lines = False

                if keep_lines:
                    #write line to new file if the line is not inbetween the VTIMEZONE lines
                    output_file.write(line)

                elif line == "END:VTIMEZONE\n":
                    #When the END:VTIMEZONE line is reached, start writing lines again
                    keep_lines = True
```

will output a new file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//TEST//TEST//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:Testing
DTEND;TZID=UTC+11:20170228T233000
DTSTAMP:20170227T064302Z
DTSTART;TZID=UTC+11:20170228T230000
UID:1961094_636238800000000000
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

from an input:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//TEST//TEST//EN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:UTC+11
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20170101
TZNAME:UTC+11
TZOFFSETFROM:+1100
TZOFFSETTO:+1100
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:Testing
DTEND;TZID=UTC+11:20170228T233000
DTSTAMP:20170227T064302Z
DTSTART;TZID=UTC+11:20170228T230000
UID:1961094_636238800000000000
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

### Alternatively

To save the lines that are to be kept, you can use the same approach however instead of opening a new file and writing the lines there, you can create a new list `lines_to_keep =[]` and do `lines_to_keep.append(line)` instead of `output_file.write(line)`:

```
lines_to_keep = []

with open("help.ics","r") as input_file:
        input_lines = input_file.readlines()

        keep_lines = True

        for line in input_lines:

            if line == "BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\n":
                keep_lines = False

            if keep_lines:

                #add the line to the list instead of writing it to a new file
                lines_to_keep.append(line)

            elif line == "END:VTIMEZONE\n":
                keep_lines = True
```

Then the `lines_to_keep` list contains all the lines that you wanted to keep therefore running:

```
for line in lines_to_keep:
    print(line)
```

Would output:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR

VERSION:2.0

PRODID:-//TEST//TEST//EN

END:VTIMEZONE

BEGIN:VEVENT

DESCRIPTION:Testing

DTEND;TZID=UTC+11:20170228T233000

DTSTAMP:20170227T064302Z

DTSTART;TZID=UTC+11:20170228T230000

UID:1961094_636238800000000000

END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

Note that the actual items in the list would look like:

```
['BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n', 'VERSION:2.0\n', 'PRODID:-//TEST//TEST//EN\n', 'END:VTIMEZONE\n', 'BEGIN:VEVENT\n', 'DESCRIPTION:Testing\n', 'DTEND;TZID=UTC+11:20170228T233000\n', 'DTSTAMP:20170227T064302Z\n', 'DTSTART;TZID=UTC+11:20170228T230000\n', 'UID:1961094_636238800000000000\n', 'END:VEVENT\n', 'END:VCALENDAR']
```

The `\n` represents a new line. Without it, if you were to write these lines to a new file, they would be written on the same line. The `\n` appears there in the first place because it is read in by `input_file.readlines()`.

If you would like to convert these to just be the string of what the actual line is eg `'BEGIN:VCALENDAR'` instead of `'BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n'`, you could run through each line in the list and if it ends in '\n' remove it:

```
for line_index in range(len(lines_to_keep)):
    if lines_to_keep[line_index].endswith('\n'):
        lines_to_keep[line_index] = lines_to_keep[line_index][:-1]
```

Which changes each line to itself, without the last two characters, if it ends in '\n'.

Comment: Adam, thanks for this. Please see my final code where I used io.StringIO() for in memory strings. For some reason when I ran your first code it didnt remove the line END:VTIMEZONE, so I added if keep_lines==True and line != "END:VTIMEZONE\n": tehn append the line.

Comment: The reason why it didn't remove the last line was my mistake in that the order in which I was checking the lines and keeping them meant that when the 'END:VTIMEZONE' line was reached, the 'keep_lines' variable would become TRUE meaning that immediately after that same line was kept. 
Changing the order to write the line: 'if keep_lines:

                lines_to_keep.append(line)'
before 'elif line == "END:VTIMEZONE\n":
                keep_lines = True'
fixes this! I edited my answer to include this fix. Your solution also works :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Adam's help this was my final code. My subtle difference was I wrote to IO memory (import io) as opposed to file.

```
ics_temp=io.StringIO()
with open(ics_local,"r") as input_file:
    #read in each line as a list
    input_lines = input_file.readlines()
    ics_temp=io.StringIO()
    keep_lines = True   #variable to IOStream or not
    for line in input_lines:    #loop thorugh every line
        if line == "BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\n":
            #When the BEGIN:VTIMEZONE line is reached, stop writing lines
            keep_lines = False
        elif line == "END:VTIMEZONE\n":
            #When the END:VTIMEZONE line is reached, start writing lines again
            keep_lines = True
        if keep_lines==True and line != "END:VTIMEZONE\n":
            ics_temp.write(line)       #write line to ioString inbetween the VTIMEZONE lines

ics_file=ics_temp.getvalue()
ics_temp.close()
print(ics_file)
```